# View Does Not Reflect Updated Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form submission using HTML helpers and a `p` tag that displays a simple count.

On page load, the count in the p tag is obviously 0, which is derived from a list in the model by calling `@Model.Individual.Count`. After the form is submitted, I'm expecting the Individual list should have a Count of 1. This is indeed the case when I'm debugging it through Visual Studio. I can see it being updated in the model and hitting the breakpoints in the View and `@Model.Individual.Count` has a value of 1. But then when the page loads in the browser, the value in the p tag still says 0.

I have no idea what is going on since the debug value says 1 but it displays 0 in the browser...

Answer (score 0):

It appears this was due to page life-cycle events and at which times certain scripts were being loaded during the page events. Additionally, since I have desktop and mobile scripts running on the same .cshtml file (loading them or not loading them depending on the screen size), conflicts were occurring.

Overall, the problem was with scripts being fired at the correct times during the page life-cycle.